# Remove the specific column in table

Tags: javascript, css

I'm struggling with the table column hide and show using check box.  I want to remove the Mars column(Bold) and with respective data(Bold).

After removing the Mars column,  Venus and its respected data values to be centered in the table.

check here: http://jsfiddle.net/bL44n3aj/3/

After Removing Mars Column, I want this Output : http://jsfiddle.net/2Lcsc2go/

My CSS and HTML part:

```css
td{
  border:1px solid #000;
  
}
th{
  border:1px solid red;
  font-weight:normal !important;
}

tr.sub-header th{
  text-align:center !important;
   border:1px solid blue !important;
   font-weight:bold !important;
}

tr.sub-header-value td{
  text-align:center !important;
  font-weight:bold !important;
}
```

```html
<table width="80%">
  <tr>
  <th>Produced</th>
    <th>Sold</th>
    <th>Produced</th>
    <th>Sold</th>
  
    </tr>
  <tr class="sub-header">
    <th colspan="2">Mars</th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">Venus</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>50,000</td>
    <td>30,000</td>
    <td>100,000</td>
    <td>80,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub-header-value">
     <td colspan="2">Mars data</td>
    <td colspan="2"> Venus data </td>
    
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
 
    <td>10,000</td>
    <td>5,000</td>
    <td>12,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
  </tr>
   <tr class="sub-header-value">
     <td colspan="2">Mars data</td>
    <td colspan="2">Venus data</td>
    
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="checkbox"> Remove Mars
```

Comment: Where's your javascript? You can include js in the stackoverflow snippet, you know.

Comment: I don't quite understand this explanation: **"After removing the Mars column, Venus and its respected data values to be centered in the table."**
Do you know how to do this with html/css? If so, please add an example of the expected output. Or make an image sketch of what you want.

Comment: @Haken Lid When you remove the Mars column, the Mars Data should be removed... then the Venus column and Its Venus data should be centered.

Comment: I want this output after removing Mars column http://jsfiddle.net/2Lcsc2go/

Comment: You should edit you original question to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a hacky way. To make it less hacky, you would need to add classes to all of the tds.

I'm using jQuery, do you want a JavaScript version?

```js
$(function(){
  var removed = false;
  $("#removeMars").click(function(){
    if (!removed) {
      $.each($("#t tr"), function(){
        var tds = $(this).find("th, td");
        if (tds.length == 2) {
          $(tds[1]).attr("colspan", "4");
          $(tds[0]).remove();
        }
      })
      removed = true;
    }
  })
})
```

```css
td{
  border:1px solid #000;
  
}
th{
  border:1px solid red;
}

tr.sub-header th{
  text-align:center !important;
   border:1px solid blue !important;
   font-weight:bold !important;
}

tr.sub-header-value td{
  text-align:center !important;
  font-weight:bold !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="t" width="80%">
  <tr>
  <th>Produced</th>
    <th>Sold</th>
    <th>Produced</th>
    <th>Sold</th>
  
    </tr>
  <tr class="sub-header">
    <th colspan="2" >Mars</th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">Venus</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>50,000</td>
    <td>30,000</td>
    <td>100,000</td>
    <td>80,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub-header-value">
     <td colspan="2">Mars data</td>
    <td colspan="2"> Venus data </td>
    
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
 
    <td>10,000</td>
    <td>5,000</td>
    <td>12,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
  </tr>
   <tr class="sub-header-value">
     <td colspan="2">Mars data</td>
    <td colspan="2">Venus data</td>
    
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="checkbox" id="removeMars"> Remove Mars
```

Comment: @sivakumaronline I did. Mars' column is deleted after one click.

Answer (score 1):

The completed Solution:

```
 $(function(){
  var removed = false;
 $("#removeMars").change(function(){
        if(this.checked) {
    if (!removed) {
      $.each($("#t tr"), function(){
        var tds = $(this).find("th, td");

        if (tds.length == 2) {
          $(tds[1]).attr("colspan", "4");
          $(tds[0]).hide();

        }
      })
      removed = true;
    }
    }
    else{
         $.each($("#t tr"), function(){
        var tds = $(this).find("th, td");

        if (tds.length == 2) {
          $(tds[1]).attr("colspan", "2");
          $(tds[0]).show();

        }
      })    
      removed = false;
    }

  })
})
```

Check this Fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/qLo60ux8/